# why does importing keras take so long on AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, keras, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

## Problem

I'm trying to load and use a `keras` model in AWS Lambda, but importing `keras` from `tensorflow` is taking a long time in my lambda function. Curiously, though, it didn't take very long in `SageMaker`. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

## Setup Description

I'm using the [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/) to deploy my function. The handler and serverless.yml are included below. I have an EFS volume holding my dependencies, which were installed using an EC2 instance with the EFS volume mounted. I `pip` installed dependencies to the EFS with the `-t` flag. For example, I installed tensorflow like this:

```
sudo miniconda3/envs/devenv/bin/pip install tensorflow -t /mnt/efs/fs1/lib
```

where `/mnt/efs/fs1/lib` is the folder on the EFS which stores my dependencies. The models are stored on s3.

I prototyped my loading my model on a Sagemaker notebook with the following code:

```
import time
start = time.time()

from tensorflow import keras
print('keras: {}'.format(time.time()-start))
import boto3
import os
import zipfile
print('imports: {}'.format(time.time()-start))

modelPath = '***model.zip'
bucket = 'predictionresources'


def load_motion_model():
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.download_file(bucket, modelPath, 'model.motionmodel.zip')
    
    with zipfile.ZipFile('model.motionmodel.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall('model.motionmodel')
        
    return keras.models.load_model('model.motionmodel/'+os.listdir('model.motionmodel')[0])

model = load_motion_model()

print('total time: {}'.format(time.time()-start))
```

which has the following output:

```
keras: 2.0228586196899414
imports: 2.0231151580810547
total time: 3.0635251998901367
```

so, including all imports, this takes around 3 seconds to execute.

however, when I deploy to AWS Lambda with serverless, keras takes substantially longer to import. This lambda function (which is the same as the other one, just wrapped in a handler) and serverless.yml:

### Handler

```
try:
    import sys
    import os
    sys.path.append(os.environ['MNT_DIR']+'/lib0')  # nopep8 # noqa
except ImportError:
    pass

#returns the version of all dependancies
def test(event, context):
    print('TEST LOADING')

    import time
    start = time.time()

    from tensorflow import keras
    print('keras: {}'.format(time.time()-start))
    import boto3
    import os
    import zipfile
    print('imports: {}'.format(time.time()-start))

    modelPath = '**********nmodel.zip'
    bucket = '***********'


    def load_motion_model():
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        s3.download_file(bucket, modelPath, 'model.motionmodel.zip')
        
        with zipfile.ZipFile('model.motionmodel.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall('model.motionmodel')
            
        return keras.models.load_model('model.motionmodel/'+os.listdir('model.motionmodel')[0])

    model = load_motion_model()

    print('total time: {}'.format(time.time()-start))

    body = {
        'message': 'done!'
    }

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(body)
    }

    return response
```

(p.s. I know this would fail due to lack of write access, and the model needs to be saved to `/tmp/`)

### Serverless.yml

```
service: test4KerasTest

plugins:
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

custom:
  efsAccessPoint: fsap-*****
  LocalMountPath: /mnt/efs
  subnetsId: subnet-*****
  securityGroup: sg-*****

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  region: us-east-2
  timeout: 30

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:GetObject
        - s3:PutObject
      Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::predictionresources/*'

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - .vscode/**
    - .serverless/**
    - .pytest_cache/**
    - __pychache__/**

functions:
  test:
    handler: handler.test
    environment: # Service wide environment variables
      MNT_DIR: ${self:custom.LocalMountPath}
      BUCKET: predictionresources
      REGION: us-east-2
    vpc:
      securityGroupIds:
        - ${self:custom.securityGroup}
      subnetIds:
        - ${self:custom.subnetsId}
    iamManagedPolicies:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonElasticFileSystemClientReadWriteAccess
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
    events:
      - http:
          path: test
          method: get
    fileSystemConfig:
      localMountPath: '${self:custom.LocalMountPath}'
      arn: 'arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:access-point/${self:custom.efsAccessPoint}'
```

results in this output from cloudwatch:

[image: cloudwatch output, keras import time is drastically longer]

As can be seen, keras takes substantially longer to import in my lambda environment, but the other imports don't seem to be as negatively effected. I have tried importing different modules in different orders, and keras consistently takes an unreasonable amount of time to import.. Due to restrictions by the API Gateway, this function can't take longer than 30 seconds, which means I have to find a way to shorten the time it takes me to import `keras` on my lambda function.

Comment: How much memory have you allocated to the function? I don't see anything in your serverless.yml, so I'm guessing it's a default value; maybe 512 MB? Lambda only gives you a fraction of a CPU until you get to just under 2 GB.

Comment: I'm currently using the default allocation. Thanks for the tip I'll try upping my allocation.

Comment: For those interested, that did help a bit, but not substantially. If you're riding the line slightly upping your memory allocation may be a useful strategy.